# NSString to NSData conversion Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, nsdata

I have some Bytes of  image  in my string and i want to draw it to UIImageView  ...Here is my code

```
NSString* str= @"<89504e47 0d0a1a0a 0000000d 49484452 ........... 454e44ae 426082>";
    NSData* data=[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
    NSLog(@"My NSDATA  %@",data);
    imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Now when i saw that printed data on console it is not in same format what i gave to that string..The output is something like.....

```
<3c383935 30346534 37203064 30613161..........
```

So my imageview show nothing..... please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if question was: How to convert string data to image then this is answer.

```
NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"icon" ofType:@"png"]];
// set your string data into inputString var
NSString *inputString = [imgData description];
NSLog(@"input string  %@",inputString);
// clearing string from trashes
NSString *dataStr = [inputString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
// separate by words of 4 bytes
NSArray *words = [dataStr componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
// calculate number of bytes
NSArray *sizes = [words valueForKey:@"length"];
int sizeOfBytes = 0;
for (NSNumber *size in sizes) {
    sizeOfBytes += [size intValue]/2;
}
int bytes[sizeOfBytes];
int counts = 0;
for (NSString *word in words) {
    // convert each word from string to int
    NSMutableString *ostr = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[word length]];
    while ([word length] > 0) {
        [ostr appendFormat:@"%@", [word substringFromIndex:[word length] - 2]];
        word = [word substringToIndex:[word length] - 2];
    }

    NSScanner *scaner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:ostr];
    unsigned int val;
    [scaner scanHexInt:&val];
    bytes[counts] = val;
    counts++;
}
// get NSData form c array
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:sizeOfBytes];
NSLog(@"My NSDATA  %@",data);
// your image is ready
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
NSLog(@"image: %@",image);
```

Comment: down voted because it doesn't explain in any way what the code does, or what it should do. therefor it doesn't answer the question, but simply injects a random piece of code into the world..

Comment: I added some comments, maybe this help you to understand what happens

Answer (score 1):

what you are seeing in NSLog output are the ASCII codes of the string characters.
for example:

```
NSString* str = @"A";
NSData* data=[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
NSLog(@"%@",data);
```

you will see something like:

> <41....

that's because 0x41 is the code for letter A.

Same is happening with your string.

Comment: You'll have to provide a scenario of what exactly you are trying to do. I'm not sure what do you mean by 'image bytes in a string'.

Answer (score 0):

The data is *exactly* what you're feeding it: a simple string (printed as raw byte values). But I guess your input string is a hexdump and you manually need to turn into bytes.